# Automatically rename class to match file name

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-5.1

I have a class `A` in file `B.cs`. Now I want to rename this class to match the file name (`B`).

Is there a refactoring or context action in VS or ReSharper which **automatically** can do this renaming for me **without typing in the new name** matching file name?

### Example

**Before renaming:**

File B.cs:

```
class A {}
```

**After automatically renaming:**

File B.cs:

```
class B{}
```

### Update

The **opposite** (automatically rename file to match class name) **is not an option** because all these file renamings are implemented as DELETE+ADD. But then I **would lose change history** of that file in Perforce because all VS-Plug-ins for VS-Perforce-connection do not support *move/add+move/delete* actions for renaming.

Comment: Is it too hard to use Resharper renaming feature to rename the class by copy-pasting the filename in the box? IE: Do you have 50 classes to rename or just 2-3?

Comment: I need to rename many (~100) classes after our naming scheme was changed. So I renamed the files in Perforce at first (because renaming in VS would removing the change history). And now I try to adjust the class names to new naming schema. And of course the class names are much longer than just `A` or `B`.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but DevExpress' CodeRush/Refactor product *does* have this as an available refactor.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573024/renaming-files-in-perforce) seems to be the same. There is an accepted answer, but I can't tell if it will actually solve your problem.

Comment: @comecme Of course Perforce client P4V does not delete file history. I'm using it for that. But then I want to rename class name to match file name.

Comment: JetBrains Rider 2023.3.2 does not have this feature. I dont think it is a requested enough feature to be included. (Even though I would like to have it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently did a large refactor of several files, changing them from "Controllers" to "Services". After plodding through a few of them with ReSharper, I decided I should rename "BaseController" to "BaseService". Ding! ReSharper offered to rename all subclasses and replace "Controller" with "Service".

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, you can right click on the class name inside the .cs file and rename it by choosing "Refactor --> Rename". It will give you the option to refactor it.

Comment: I would also suggest downloading "ReSharper" - with that you can just put the cursor on it and Alt+Enter+Enter.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to type in the name. VS/ReSharper sould automatically get the file name. I updated my question by that point.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I don't mean *Rename file to matching type name* context action. I mean the opposite like **"Rename type to matching file name"**.

Comment: @thersch I'm not aware of a feature for that, and I also can't really think of a good-enough need for that.

Comment: @YoryeNathan If you would need to rename ~100 classes and want to keep change history you would also need such a feature. :-)

Comment: @thersch But the code goes by class name, not by file name - that means nothing to the infrastructure, really. I can't see why the file name and class name should be different in the first place.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Of course the application also compiles and runs if file names are different to class names. But the readability of code is harder and it is confusing. (We use Solution Explorer for manual navigations.)

Comment: @thersch I meant that the class name itself should be a meaningful one - probably the one you want to rename it to just now - in the first place. Having the file name meaningful as well is a good bonus.

Comment: @YoryeNathan You are right if you only use Ctrl+Click/F12 and ReSharper's Ctrl+T navigation. But we also use Solution Explorer for navigation to classes frequently. And Solution Explorer has **file names**. So for our team it's a must to rename files too.

Comment: @thersch It's not a question about whether files should be renamed or not - they should. It's a matter of which name comes first - the file after the class or the class after the file, and it will probably come from the class, not the file, so... I don't see how you got yourself into this trouble. When the class name is good, you just Alt+Enter+Enter and the file name matches it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Ok I could change class name **before** file name and use Alt+Enter+Enter to automatically change the file name. I could also check option *Synchronize file names accordingly to changes* in renaming dialog (Ctrl+R,Ctrl+R). **But then I would lose change history in Perforce** because VS does a delete/add for a rename. Because of that lack the order of renaming class and file does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

With Resharper you can use Ctrl+R,O

[image]

P.S. I use Resharper 6.1

Comment: It was a typo. It should have been Ctrl+R/Ctrl+O

Comment: Isn't it Ctrl+R, O then? Or is it two different sequences of keys presses?

Comment: I don't mean "Move to another file". I mean an action like "Rename type to matching file name".

Comment: Just delete the old file then..?

Comment: To thersch, as I know Resharper doesn't have such a feature out of the box. But it is very extensible, so it is not a problem to make a plugin with such functionality.

Comment: @Pacane Deleting file is not an option. I have improved my (possible poor) question by adding an example with *before* and *after* states.

Comment: @AndreiSchneider Thanks for the hint to writing a plug-in. But I think it is to much time for me to learn ReSharper's plug-in interface. I tried Live Template because there is a macro *Current file name without extension*. But this would change just the one place of class name and not update all other references to this class name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a refactoring or context action in VS or ReSharper which **automatically** can do this renaming for me **without typing in the new name** matching file name?

With ReShaper 8.1 it is possible. Just put a cursor on the class name, hit `alt + Enter` to bring up the options then Select '`Rename file to match type name`' and you are good.

[image]

Comment: This is the wrong direction. I searched after a "Rename type name to match file name".

Comment: It's right direction if you are using resharper V 8.1.  As you can see in the gif image above.  If is not working for you,  check which version of resharper you are using.

Comment: I wanted to change the class name, not the file name. Your gif image keeps the class name with "A" and changes the file name from "B" to "A".

Comment: To change class name, use resharper rename feature. Put cursor on a what you want to rename (in your case it's a class name) then Ctrl + R + R to rename the class name. This will rename class and all the places where it has been used.  Note: this can be done from anywhere where the class name is used,  it's not must to do it from class file.

Comment: @iAM No it's not the right direction. You didn't even bother to actually read the question title: **Automatically rename CLASS to match FILE name**. And that is the far more frequent usecase. You have a file with a class in it, you want to change the file name and consequently automatically change the class name and all its references.